# Imposible agregar header authorization : basic user:password (base16) vue-resource

Tags: javascript, api

Tengo una aplicacion en VUE en la que hago peticiones a dos API's, una es mia y la otra de un tercero, con la mia no tengo problemas, puedo autenticarme y hacer peticiones de forma correcta, en el main.js puse por defecto un interceptador que agregara al token de autenticación:

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
  request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.token)
  next()
  })
```

Efectivamente todo va bien y pudo autenticarme y hacer peticiones, el problema es con la otra API que no me pertenece y a la que debo hacerle peticiones luego de logueado, tengo un componente welcome al que en el created le pongo una peticion get de esta forma:

```
created () {
this.$http.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic xxxxxxx'

this.$http.get('https://pag.com/13906/dataserver/api/v1//xxxx', 
{
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic xxxxx',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'        
  }})
.then(response => {
console.log(response)
})
}
```

Y me tira este error:
[image: error]

La api esta protegida por autenticación basica, a ella puedo acceder bien a traves del navegador o postman, me comunique el dueño y no tiene bloqueado accesos por fuera del dominio, es simplemente que no logro enviar el header de ninguna manera, si miro en la consola de red obtengo esto:
[image: peticion]

Como se puede ver la cabecera Authentication no es enviada, pero si edito la cabecera y la agrego manualmente:
[image: editando cabeceras]

Entonces la peticion que antes me daba 401 ahora me retorna status 200:

[image: ok]

Por favor como puedo agregar la cabecera por vue-resource

Answer (score 1):

imagino que usas axios, te recomiendo configuralo por tu cuenta y puedas crear dos HTTP sin que interfieran

```js
export const HTTP = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.API_URL,
  timeout: 300000,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${store ? store.getters['auth/access_token'] : ''}`,
  },
});


export const HTTP_THIRD_PARTY = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.API_URL_THIRD_PARTY,
  timeout: 300000,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `BASIC ....`,
  },
});

// other file or wherever you want
import {HTTP, HTTP_THIRD_PARTY} from './services'

export default {
  async mounted() {
    await HTTP.get(....)
    await HTTP_THIRD_PARTY.get(...)
  }
}
```

De igual manera lo puedes agregar a un prototipo de Vue

Comment: Uso vue-resource, pero si es conveniente aun cuando solo deseo cambiar el header en un par de ocaciones?

Comment: leí la documentación y me pareció un poco limitado para lo que quieres hacer, tal vez puedas extender de la funcionalidad base pero no imagino tener dos llamados consecutivos y estar haciendo switch de headers, no suena elegante, de hecho tienen un issue abierto [aquí](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/issues/696) relacionado a lo que estas haciendo, yo buscaría algo como axios es realmente simple de usar y configurar en caso que no quieras gastar mucho tiempo haciendo una solución propia

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar, simplemente no se agrega, aun usando ajax y vanilla javascript simplemente no se me refleja la cabecera Authorization basic en mi cabecera de peticion